# GUI Text counter Skips numbers after a few seconds

Tags: c#, unity, gui

[image]

The counter counts perfectly up until the first bump. After this it starts to add about 4-5 "points" instead of just 1.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GUIText scoreText;
    public int score;

// CONVERT FLOAT TO INT?


    void Start (){
    score = 0;
    StartCoroutine (FeetScoreCounter());
    }

    // STARTS COUNTING AFTER WAITFORSECONDS
    IEnumerator FeetScoreCounter() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
    InvokeRepeating("scoreCounter", 2, 1);
}

// FOR EACH 5 SECONDS; score++ ???

    void Update () {
    scoreText.text = score + " ft";
 //     StartCoroutine (FeetScoreCounter());

}

void scoreCounter () {
    score += 1;
    StartCoroutine (FeetScoreCounter());
    score ++;
}

}
```

I want my counter to start counting when the game starts, to show how far up the balloon is. I am incapable of seeing why my code just randomly adds a whole lot more over time. Care to help?

Comment: It adds a whole lot of numbers because your logic is crazy! If your character moves down the screen at the same pace every single time then why not just set your score to "(int)Time.time" which is the amount of time in seconds that the scene has been running for?

Comment: A combination of me being new to programming, tired and classmates playing rave-music in 100 decibels does disturb my thinking for quite a bit. Thanks for the answer, I will look into it. :)

Comment: We all have to start somewhere! :) Good luck

Comment: void Start (){score = Time.time;}
void Update () {scoreText.text = score + " ft";}
It feels like something along those lines are correct. It might be better if I just supress my excitement for a couple hours until I get home.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have your score working using `Time.time` as the counter.

I thought it may be helpful to explain what was happening when the code in your question is executed.

1. When game starts and the `Start()` method runs it calls `StartCoroutine (FeetScoreCounter())`
2. When `FeetScoreCounter()` runs it immediately yields for one second, then after that delay it calls `InvokeRepeating("scoreCounter", 2, 1)`.  This will cause `scoreCounter()` to run repeatedly starting after a two second delay, and then again every second.
3. When `scoreCounter()` runs it: A) increments `score`, B) calls `FeetScoreCounter()` (see step 2) , and then C) increments score again.

The first time `InvokeRepeating("scoreCounter", 2, 1)` is executed it causes `scorecounter()` to run in a repeating manner: wait couple of seconds then once per second until canceled.

Each subsequent call of `InvokeRepeating("scoreCounter", 2, 1)` has the same effect, but the earlier ones are never canceled.

Each time `scoreCounter()` runs it calls `FeetScoreCounter()` (and `InvokeRepeating()`) triggering an additional call of `scoreCounter()` to occur each second from then on.

As a result you quickly have many parallel `InvokeRepeating()` requests each calling `scoreCounter()` on a regular schedule.  This will cause the score to increase at an exponential rate.

---

An alternative implementation might look like this:

```
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {

    public GUIText scoreText;
    public int score;
    public int delay = 2;
    public int frequency = 1;

    void Start () {
        score = 0;
        InvokeRepeating("scoreCounter", delay, frequency);
    }

    void scoreCounter () {
        score++;
        scoreText.text = score + " ft";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This was the correct solution, where it converts score (float) to an integer.